# openGL ES retina support

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, retina-display

I'm trying to get the avTouch sample code app to run on the retina display. Has anyone done this?

In the CALevelMeter class, I've tried the following:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
 if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
      CGFloat f = self.contentScaleFactor;
      if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(contentScaleFactor)])
      {
           self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
      }
      f = self.contentScaleFactor;

      _showsPeaks = YES;
      _channelNumbers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
      _vertical = NO;
      _useGL = YES;
      _meterTable = new MeterTable(kMinDBvalue);
      [self layoutSubLevelMeters];
      [self registerForBackgroundNotifications];
 }
 return self;
```

}

and it sets the contentScaleFactor to "2". Great, that was expected. But then in the layoutSubviews, CALevelMeter frame is still 1/2 of what it should be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Frames are in points, not pixels.  When a scale factor is applied to the UIView hosting your CAEAGLLayer, it will be double the pixels, but its frame point size will remain the same.

If you look at the backing width and height for the color renderbuffer attached to the CAEAGLLayer using code like the following:

```
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);
```

you should see that the width and height of the renderbuffer on a Retina display are twice the values they are on a standard iPhone display.

The code you show above should cause nice, sharp rendering on a Retina display.

EDIT (12/22/2010): In response to your further question, looking at the avTouch sample code shows that the current version of that code makes a mistake in looking up the bounds of the OpenGL-hosting view, rather than using the backing width and height of the renderbuffer.  With a non-1.0 scale factor, this will cause the OpenGL content to be drawn at half size.

To fix this, replace the appropriate section within `_drawView` in GLLevelMeter with the following code:

```
if (_vertical)
{
    glTranslatef(0., _backingWidth, 0.);
    glScalef(1., -1., 1.);
    bds = CGRectMake(0., 0., _backingWidth, _backingHeight);
} else {
    glTranslatef(0., _backingHeight, 0.);
    glRotatef(-90., 0., 0., 1.);
    bds = CGRectMake(0., 0., _backingHeight, _backingWidth);
}
```

This will cause everything to work in the appropriate pixel space, and lead to crisp rendering at the correct size in the equalizer.  I've filed a bug report on this.

Comment: But doesn't the retina display double the frame size to account for the higher resolution? Even after adding the code I mentioned, I still only get a meter thats 1/2 the height. This is only the case for the openGL meter. The UIView meter works fine with retina. I'm stumped.

Comment: @Bryan - Looking at the avTouch sample code, it appears that Apple has made an error in the way they've implemented `_drawView` in GLLevelMeter.  They are using the bounds of the view, which is in points, to determine sizes of things in OpenGL, when instead they should be using the `_backingWidth` and `_backingHeight` instance variables.  Replace references to the bounds' size and height with `_backingWidth` and `_backingHeight` and this will draw properly on a Retina display.  I'll file a bug report on the sample code.

Comment: @Bryan - I've localized the code that needs to be changed within the edit to my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. I'm new to openGL and was thinking the frame got adjusted based on the contentScaleFactor, but clearly not. Thanks again!