# unity disable retina for iphone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, screen, unity-game-engine

We developing an app for iOS with Unity (Basic version).
On iPhone 4 we have low fps.
We want to use non-retina 320*480 screen size on iPhone 4 (and render buffer 320*480).
We think that will increase performance on iPhone 4.
We know how to do this in iOS app through code (as for example shown here [openGL ES retina support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504614/opengl-es-retina-support)).
How can we do this through Unity?
Are there any ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Unity3d and go to Player Setting of iOS:

- Setting for iOS > Other Setting  > Target Resolution > Select 320(iPhone).
- If your app is not using Accelerometer then Disable Accelerometer Frequency.
- Also in Optimisation : Script Call Optimization = Fast but no Exception.